# combine vector to data frame by rownames filling gaps with zeros

Tags: r, vector

i have the following conundrum. I have a dataframe x that looks like:

```
     v2      v3    
10   4.0      3.0
11   5.0      3.0
12   6.0      9.0
13   5.0      6.0    # where 10-14 are rownames
14   3.0      6.0
```

and then the datafame y:

```
     value        
11   99            
13   88      #where 11,13,14 are row names
14   33
```

I would like to add value to x matching the rownames and filling the gaps with zeros.i.e.:

```
      v2      v3    value
10   4.0      3.0     0
11   5.0      3.0     99
12   6.0      9.0      0
13   5.0      6.0     88
14   3.0      6.0     33
```

Although if I have to fill with NAs maybe I can do this and then change NAs to zeros within the new y vector afterwards.

I have been trying variations of `rbind.fill` from `plyr`  using `newDF<-do.call(rbind.fill)`but nothing i am achieving is working out the way i hope.

EDIT
i GOT IT TO GIVE NAS USING
`merge(x,y,all=TRUE,by='row.names')`

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022046/how-to-merge-on-a-rowname-by-some-column-from-another-data-frame help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
y$row <- rownames(y)    # add a 'helper' column for the merge function.
x$row <- rownames(x)
n <-merge(x,y, by='row', all=T)
n <- n[,-1]    # remove the 'helper' column
```

and then replace the NAs by 0:

```
n[is.na(n$value),]$value = 0
```

But this fails, or will procude wrong results, if you have NAs in your y/x dataframe.

Comment: thanks I found the merge function just before you posted but thanks very much for the replacing with zeros.  That would have taken some time.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one column this is another approach though likely not the best one but an alternative:

```
x$value <- ifelse(rownames(x) %in% rownames(y), y$value, 0)
```